# Disable Shutdown Warning When System Accounts are Logged In

Tags: 20.04, gnome, ssh, shutdown

On Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME3:

We have a system configuration/monitoring process that uses a local account, `TEST_ACCOUNT`, to ssh into the machine at basically all times. When a user wants to power off or reboot a machine, a popup warning alerts the user that "Other users are logged in", and lists only the system account.

We have already marked it as a SystemAccount in AccountsService, as in:

```
$ sudo cat /var/lib/AccountsService/users/TEST_ACCOUNT
[User]
Session=
XSession=
SystemAccount=true
```

Is there an additional setting available to prevent the power off warning from popping up when a system account is logged into the machine? Or did we miss something when creating the local account?